# Display value derived from field instead of field itself in q-table column

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework, quasar

[image]

I have a role for a specific user with these numbers.

1. Instead of number 1 it will display the word "Super Admin"
2. Instead of number 2 it will display the word "Admin"
3. Instead of number 2 it will display the word "User"
   and so on.

I am using `q-table`

```html
     <q-table
              flat
              bordered
              title="USERS"
              :data="allUsers"
              :columns="columns"
              :filter="filter"
              :pagination.sync="initialPagination"
              row-key="id"
            >
              <template v-slot:top-right>
                <q-input
                  outlined
                  dense
                  debounce="300"
                  placeholder="Search"
                  v-model="filter"
                >
                  <template v-slot:append>
                    <q-icon name="search" />
                  </template>
                </q-input>
    
                <div class="q-pa-sm q-gutter-sm"></div>
                <q-btn
                  outline
                  color="white"
                  text-color="black"
                  @click="openCreateUserModal"
                  label="Create Users"
                />
              </template>
    
              <template v-slot:body="props">
                <q-tr :props="props">
                  <q-td
                    v-for="col in props.cols.filter(col => col.name !== 'actions')"
                    :key="col.name"
                  >
                    {{ col.value }}
                  </q-td>
    
                  <td key="actions">
                    <q-btn dense flat color="primary" field="edit" icon="edit" />
                    <q-btn
                      dense
                      flat
                      color="negative"
                      field="delete"
                      icon="delete"
                    />
                  </td>
                </q-tr>
              </template>
            </q-table>
```

The role in my column

```js
 {
      name: "role",
      align: "center",
      label: "Role",
      field: "role",
      sortable: true
    },
```

Is this possible what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Column definition [can contain](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table#defining-the-columns) `format` field to define a custom formatting function. The function is called with the 2 arguments - the value retrieved from `field` and `row` (which can be useful to create display values by combining data from multiple fields)

```js
const roleIdToRoleName = {
  1: "Super Admin",
  2: "Admin",
  3: "User"
}

...
{ 
  name: "role", 
  align: "center", 
  label: "Role", 
  field: "role", 
  sortable: true, 
  format: (val, row) => roleIdToRoleName[val] 
},
```

This works out of the box **if you do not** override default rendering by providing `body` slot. This is problematic because you will loose a lot of provided functionality:

1. `field` can be string but it can also be a function (useful to drill down to some nested object data)
2. `format` is of course not applied

Default "get cell value" functionality of `q-table` looks like something like this:

```js
const getCellValue(row, col) {
  const val = typeof col.field === 'function' ? col.field(row) : row[col.field]
  return col.format ? col.format(val, row) : val
}
```

You can of course replicate it in your code and use it:

```html
<q-td :props="props"  // !! you are missing props here
  v-for="col in props.cols.filter(col => col.name !== 'actions')"
  :key="col.name"
>
  {{ getCellValue(props.row, col) }}
</q-td>
```

**but** since it seems only reason you are overriding `body` slot is because you need custom rendering of the `actions` column, why not just use `body-cell-actions` slot instead? This will override only rendering of `actions` column and other columns will use default `q-table` rendering

Just add `actions` column in columns definition:

```js
{ name: 'actions', label: 'Action', sortable: false}
```

```html
 <template v-slot:body-cell-actions="props">
   <q-td :props="props">
     <q-btn dense flat color="primary" field="edit" icon="edit" />
     <q-btn dense flat color="negative" field="delete" icon="delete" />
   </q-td>
 </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still have computed, or calculated, or formatted columns based on values in other columns even when custom rendering the table body.

Without custom rendering the table body, you can use the `field` property on the on the columns. For example, let's say we want to calculate the difference between two values as a "computed" property. The columns definition in the script might look like:

```js
const columns = [
  {
    name: 'name',
    required: true,
    label: 'Name',
    align: 'left',
    field: 'name',
    sortable: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'planned',
    align: 'right',
    label: 'Planned',
    field: 'planned',
  },
  {
    name: 'actual',
    align: 'right',
    label: 'Actual',
    field: 'actual',
  },
  {
    name: 'difference',
    align: 'right',
    label: 'Difference',
    field: (row) => row.planned - row.actual,
  },
];

const rows = [
  {
    name: 'Amount1',
    planned: 100.0,
    actual: 300.0,
  },
  {
    name: 'Amount2',
    planned: 100.0,
    actual: 90.0,
  },
];
```

And if you use the `q-table` component out of the box

```
<template>
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <q-table
      title="Amounts"
      :rows="rows"
      :columns="columns"
      row-key="name"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

You would see the computed value work.

---

To do this with the custom rendering of the table body, to satisfy TypeScript requirements, you would leave the `field` attribute on the `columns` definition:

```js
const columns = [
  {
    name: 'name',
    required: true,
    label: 'Name',
    align: 'left',
    field: 'name',
    sortable: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'planned',
    align: 'right',
    label: 'Planned',
    field: 'planned',
  },
  {
    name: 'actual',
    align: 'right',
    label: 'Actual',
    field: 'actual',
  },
  {
    name: 'difference',
    align: 'right',
    label: 'Difference',
    field: (row) => row.planned - row.actual,
  },
];

const rows = [
  {
    name: 'Amount1',
    planned: 100.0,
    actual: 300.0,
  },
  {
    name: 'Amount2',
    planned: 100.0,
    actual: 90.0,
  },
];
```

But the actual logic that run happens where you're rendering the value in the component.

```
<template>
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <q-table title="Amounts" :rows="rows" :columns="columns" row-key="name">
      <template v-slot:body="props">
        <q-tr :props="props">
          <q-td key="name" :props="props"> {{ props.row.name }} </q-td>
          <q-td key="planned" :props="props"> {{ props.row.planned }} </q-td>
          <q-td key="actual" :props="props"> {{ props.row.actual }} </q-td>
          <q-td key="difference" :props="props">
            {{ props.row.planned - props.row.actual }}
          </q-td>
        </q-tr>
      </template>
    </q-table>
  </div>
</template>
```